# How to reset trackpad settings of a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, default-settings, system-preferences

Is there any way to reset the trackpad settings (tracking speed, scrolling speed, etc) of a Macbook Pro laptop back to "factory default"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two methods:

#### Default settings

These are the default settings on my Macbook Pro (early 2011), note that for example "Tap to Click" and the "Secondary Click" are deactivated by default.

[image]

#### Resetting tracking speed

Go to the Terminal.app and enter:

```
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scaling
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scrolling
```

There might be some additional settings, like the double-click speed, but those are not saved in this file, so I can't really say where you would edit them, if not through System Preferences.

#### Doing this automatically

Go to the Terminal.app and enter:

```
touch reset.sh
chmod +x reset.sh
open reset.sh
```

Then paste the following into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scaling
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scrolling
```

Save it and close the file. Now you can run the script using

```
./reset.sh
```

Comment: @Pacerier I edited my post above. Maybe that helps!

Comment: @Pacerier Try using "defaults delete .GlobalPreferences .com.apple.trackpad.scaling" (+ the other one) instead. These should reset to the default values instead of explicitly setting to vaues that happen to be the same as the defaults.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that seems more appropriate, I'll change it.

Comment: I hope you tested those, as I'm not currently on a Mac ;)

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it works! ;)

Comment: gosh mac is just complicated..

Comment: Haha, for some things, yes, for others, well, it depends :)

Comment: On macOS 13.2.1 Ventura, this no longer seems to work, the following error appears: "Domain (.GlobalPreferences) not found. Defaults have not been changed."

Comment: @BartDoe That's too bad, at least for macOS 12 I do not get this warning.